# how to make validates inclusion true or false work in testing rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda, model-validation

how to make validates inclusion true or false work in testing rails?

i'm using gem [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) for my testing, if i have some validates like this in my model :

```
class Draw < ActiveRecord::Base    
    validates :available, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
end
```

how to make this validate work in testing?, when i try this code in my model testing :

```
require 'test_helper'

class DrawTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  should ensure_inclusion_of(:available).in_array([true, false])
end
```

i get error like this :

```
DrawTest#test_: Draw should ensure inclusion of available in [true, false].  [/home/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/shoulda-context-1.2.1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:344]:
[true, false] doesn't match array in validation
```

how to resove this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under version 2.6.2, should-matchers issues the following warning when testing `ensure_inclusion_of(:available).in_array([true, false])`:

```
Warning from shoulda-matchers:

You are using `ensure_inclusion_of` to assert that a boolean column allows
boolean values and disallows non-boolean ones. Assuming you are using
`validates_format_of` in your model, be aware that it is not possible to fully
test this, and in fact the validation is superfluous, as boolean columns will
automatically convert non-boolean values to boolean ones. Hence, you should
consider removing this test and the corresponding validation.
```

It seems that you should just remove the test and validation.

Comment: i'm still get error @infused after update should-matchers to version 2.6.0 ?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: shoulda (3.5.0), shoulda-context (1.2.1, 1.1.6) and shoulda-matchers (2.6.2, 2.6.0)

Comment: @tardjo, based on updated info you should just remove the test and validation.

Answer (score 3):

I solved problem with like this code.

`it { should allow_value(%w(true false)).for(:done) }`

Comment: Doesn't this test checks, that `:done` field may accept Array, that will be treated as `true`?